# How to get the version of ionic framework?

Tags: ionic-framework

I wonder how to check the version of ionic. If I do `ionic -v` I get back `1.4.3`

Can that be? Wasn't 1.0.0 just released?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

That is the version number of the Ionic CLI, which is different from the version number of Ionic's library. Here are a couple easy ways to check the version.

In the browser console, you can run `ionic.version` and it will print to the console what version it is.

[image: Screenshot of Chrome Dev Tools console]

You can also look at the `bower.json` file in your app, and it will show the version number like you see here. https://github.com/ionic-in-action/chapter5/blob/master/bower.json#L5

Comment: At some point in time the object changed from `ionic` to an uppercase `Ionic`.

As of July 2017 you need to put `Ionic.version` into your console to get the version number.

Comment: Ionic.version not working should be ionic.version at least using chrome

Comment: You can also find the same data by using cmd or terminal of your editor ;Here is the command :> ionic --version

Comment: doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 236):

Run from your project folder:

```
$ ionic info

Cordova CLI: 5.0.0
Ionic Version: 1.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.3
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v0.12.2
```

If your CLI is old enough, it will say "info is not a valid task" and you can use this:

```
$ ionic lib

Local Ionic version: 1.0.1  (C:\stuff\july21app\www\lib\ionic\version.json)
Latest Ionic version: 1.0.1  (released 2015-06-30)
* Local version up to date
```

Comment: This answer should be the accepted answer. This is the only one that worked for me. `ionic -v` returned the globally installed `ionic-cli` version. `Ionic.version` or `ionic.version` in the browser does not exist in my installation.

Answer (score 30):

In the terminal following command returns the version:

```
'ionic version' or 'ionic -v'
```

returned

```
'3.2.0'
```

The above is the CLI version. Go to the project folder and use the code below like scw's answer.

```
$ cd ionic-project
$ ionic info
✔ Gathering environment info - done!

Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic 5.2.7, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.5, (and 15 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v8.12.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : OS X Yosemite
```

Comment: Quite helpful this way.

Answer (score 12):

```
$ ionic -v
```

> CLI 4.12.0
>
> you will be able to know your framework version

```
$ ionic info
```

> all details

Comment: happy to help you

Answer (score 8):

Ionic projects structure are similar as Angular projects, you can get use

> `ionic info`

command to Print project, system, and environment information.

[image]

This command is an easy way to share information about your setup. If applicable, be sure to run ionic info within your project directory to display even more information.

We may use `--json` after `ionic info` to print system/environment info in JSON format

```
ionic info --json
```

Answer (score 7):

At some point in time the object changed from `ionic` to an uppercase `Ionic`.

As of July 2017 you need to put `Ionic.version` into your console to get the version number.

Answer (score 6):

on your terminal run this command on your ionic project folder `ionic info` and you will get the following :

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.5
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node  : v8.9.3
    npm   : 6.1.0
    OS    : macOS
    Xcode : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Answer (score 6):

You can find the library version accessing the file package.json. Under `dependencies`, check the property `ionic-angular`.
You can also check the Ionic CLI version typing `ionic info` in the terminal from your project's folder.

Answer (score 5):

Running `ionic info` on your project directory give all the info you need the npm version, cli, app script and some more

Answer (score 4):

for slower machines use the browser console.

```
Ionic.version
```

It doesn't do much analysis like the terminal's

```
ionic info
```

which gathers other useful information about your ionic project.

Answer (score 3):

The method `version` on `ionic` object returns the current version in `string` format.

Answer (score 3):

$ ionic info
Ionic:

Ionic CLI : 5.4.16

Utility:

cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

NodeJS : v12.16.1
   npm    : 6.13.4
   OS     : Linux 5.3

────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

```
       Ionic CLI update available: 5.4.16 → 6.2.2

 The package name has changed from ionic to @ionic/cli!

         To update, run: npm uninstall -g ionic
             Then run: npm i -g @ionic/cli
```

────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Answer (score 2):

ionic info

This will give you the ionic version,node, npm and os.

If you need only ionic version  use **ionic -v**.

If your project's development ionic version and your global versions are different then check them by using the below commands.

To check the globally installed ionic version ionic -g and to check the project's ionic version use **ionic -g**.

To check the project's ionic version use **ionic -v** in your project path or else   **ionic info** to get the details of ionic and its dependencies.

Comment: ionic -v displays the Ionic CLI version, not the framework version. ionic info is ok since it displays both CLI and framework versions.

Answer (score 2):

`ionic -v`

> Ionic CLI update available: 5.2.4 → 5.2.5
>          Run npm i -g ionic to update

Comment: The OP specifically said they ran this exact command and it seemed to give the wrong results. It gives the version of Ionic CLI. They asked "How to get the version of ionic framework?"...

Answer (score 1):

You can use command ionic info to get details of ionic CLI , angular CLI , Node JS version and NPM version

Answer (score 1):

Run command **ionic info**

in project root folder and you will get complete information of versions

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
@angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
Cordova Platforms : none
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 4 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res                          : not installed
native-run (update available: 1.4.1) : 1.3.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/rasharma/Android/Sdk/)
NodeJS            : v12.14.1 (/home/rasharma/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin/node)
npm               : 6.13.4
OS                : Linux 5.11