# Ionic and Ionic CLI

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5, ionic-cli

Is Ionic Framework and Ionic ClI different?

I mean to say at present the latest version of Ionic Framework is 5 but when I type ionic -v it shows me 6.10.1, so What is it - Ionic framework 5 or Ionic CLI 6?

Comment: The framework is the framework, and the CLI is the command-line interface... so yes, those are two different things. It stands to reason that they can have their own versions. Check your OS's package manager to see exact versions for both.

Comment: looks like a simple dupe of [How to get the version of ionic framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304743/how-to-get-the-version-of-ionic-framework)

Comment: Thanks for the answers Mr underscore_d. That really helped